# I wrote the code right?

Tags: c#, math

[image]

According to the equation above this, I wrote here such code:

```
Double x = 16.55 * Math.Pow(10.0, -3);
Double y = -2.75;
Double z = 0.15;

Double kvadrat_koren_3 = Math.Pow(x, 1/3);
Double vozvedenie_v_stepen = Math.Pow(x, y + 2);
Double Summa_v_Skobkax = kvadrat_koren_3 + vozvedenie_v_stepen;
Double Kvadrat_koren_10 = Math.Sqrt(10.0 * Summa_v_Skobkax);
Double ArcSinus = Math.Pow(Math.Asin(z), 2) - Math.Abs(x - y);

Double Beta = Kvadrat_koren_10 * ArcSinus;

Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(Beta, 5));
```

But the calculation of the result issued: -41.31532, as needed: -40.63069.
Where am I wrong to write the expression?

P.S. I am using the latest version of SharpDevelop, and teach himself programming to change jobs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is with the following: `Math.Pow(x, 1/3);` you're using integers for 1/3, which will give you an integer result of 0, rather than 0.33333etc.

Change the expression to `Math.Pow(x, 1.0/3.0);`